# Are the rear and front wheels the same on the 2005 Audi A6 Quattro

Tags: wheels, audi, quattro, a6

I know for some cars slightly larger rear wheels are used vs. front wheels.  I'm replacing the two right side wheels and wondering if I can get the same wheel for both.

Comment: Are the existing left-side wheels the same size?

Comment: With the Quattro being AWD, I'd think not only are the tires the same, but the wheels would be as well. I think like the AWD Subies, you have to run the tires/wheel symmetrical or you risk damaging the transfer/tranny.

Comment: It is technically possible to have different sizes front and rear - many 4x4 agricultural tractors do it and all that is needed is the correct final drivr ratio or a reducer in the hub. Don’t know of a car with it though.

Answer (score 0):

For tire size or rim size, you can crosscheck on your tires.
[image: Tire size guide]

All tires have the size and spec stamped on the side. Which you can use it for reading the size of the tire and rim. So whenever you want to change the tire just look at your old tire and match it. (Unless the old tire is somehow using the wrong size?)

Comment: My car has three possible sizes - specified by the manufacturer on a sticker in the car, so changing size is possible and it is NOT limited to what is fitted already.

Comment: Like is said :"(Unless the old tire is somehow using the wrong size?)"

Comment: Like I pointed out, for my car, any of 3 sizes are not wrong...

Comment: However for a Quattro, the tyres have to be exactly matched. Even tread depth differences can make the car unstable. (Yes, sets are best replaced all at once)